# I have a list of items and have copied it to a collection. If any changes happen to the list it should automatically reflect in the collection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

My Project is

> Step 1: Create a C# console application which should create a list of type String and add item1, item 2 and item 3.
>
> Step 2: Create a Collection of type String and copy these items.
>
> Step 3: If any change happens in the List object, it should reflect in the Collection object.

I did successfully till step 2 and my code is

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> newList = new List<string>();
            newList.Add("Item 1");
            newList.Add("Item 2");
            newList.Add("Item 3");

            Collection<string> newColl = new Collection<string>();

            foreach (string item in newList)
            {
                newColl.Add(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The items in the collection are");
            foreach (string item in newColl)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Now if changes happen in the list how will it reflect in the collections objects as well?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Do you mean what happens if you change "Item 3" in `newList` to "Item 4" for example?

Comment: It says "If any change happens in the List object, it should reflect in the Collection object." so it means if i change the item 3 to item 4, it should change in collections too @DanielKelley

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of `List<string>` and subscribe to the event `CollectionChanged`. This is very naive implementation just to give general idea. You should add check of arguments or do another types of synchronization, because you said nothing on how exactly changes should be reflected on `Collection`

```
ObservableCollection<string> newList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
newList.Add("Item 1");
newList.Add("Item 2");
newList.Add("Item 3");

Collection<string> newColl = new Collection<string>();


newList.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => 
        {
            foreach (var newItem in args.NewItems)
            {
                newColl.Add(newItem);
            }
            foreach (var removedItem in args.OldItems)
            {
                newColl.Remove(removedItem);
            }
        };
```